# Certain methods unavailable from object despite having correct using directive

Tags: c#, .net, oop, methods

I wrote some code that generates a JSON Web Token for api-authentication. It works perfectly when I run it directly in the main method as a console application in Visual Studio. However, I need the code to run within the context of another piece of software (Blue Prism to be specific), and here I encounter some strange errors. I attempted to create a class with a method that performs the needed task, but here some methods within an instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider are unavailable.

[Code running in main method (this works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfYev.png)

[Code in method definition for a class (does not work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcVef.png)

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUZEt.png)

Now, the error message claims no definition for the "importPkcs8PrivateKey" method exists. RSACryptoServiceProvider is defined within the System.Security.Cryptography namespace, which I have a using directive for. And as previously stated the code does work when run in the main method. Some methods are available from the object, but some others aren't, like "ImportRSAPrivateKey". The common factor I can find between the unavailable methods is that they either have the "override" keyword, or the "virtual" keyword, but I'm not sure if this is the cause. You might also notice that the struct "ReadOnlySpan" is unavailable in the second image. This is a public struct in the System namespace, so I am having a hard time understanding why this is also unavailable.

Comment: Please add your code as formatted code rather than an image of code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are attempting to use is only available in .NET Core 3.0 or .NET 5.0 and later; [see MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importpkcs8privatekey?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_ImportPkcs8PrivateKey_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Int32__).

An alternative for .NET Framework is [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62573149/23633).